# Enable-Migrations not working in project with existing db configurations

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run the `Enable-Migrations` cmd-let in a solution with an already existing db configuration, but no matter what combination of options I try, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid directory on URL."
At my-project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At my-project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Invalid directory on URL."
At my-project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

The solution is structured like this:

```
Foo.sln
┖─ DbCreator (command line program, transfers data from an old db)
┖─ Foo.Api (WebAPI project, default startup project)
┖─ Foo.Repository (Contains entities and DbContext)
┖─ other utility and test projects
```

What I'd like to do, is to look at the `DbContext` in `Foo.Repository` (the only one in the solution), and enable migrations into the `DbCreator` project, so I can run the migrations every time I run the exe.

I'm using VS 2015 and EF 6.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a know issue, for workaround have a look at [1950#issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1950#issue-65169768.raw)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I managed to work around it by doing a complete re-structure of my EF code, too (since migrations worked in a clean project) but that might of course not be feasible to anyone.